# Take inputs to run a program and display output on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i want to take inputs from a webpage to run a function on js and display it back to the web page. For some reason, the function is not executing/ posting if i am taking inputs from the web page but display's fine if i give the values in the js code itself. Please Help.

The output is not coming out as expected. I want the fields Country name and rate check to be the values for my function and the result to be displayed after the rate label

HTML

```
<form>
    Country Name: <input type="text" name="A"> <br>
    Rate Check: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;    <input type="text" name="B"> <br>
    Rate : <label id="Rate"> </label> <br>
</form> <br>
<button onclick="LookUp(CountryName, prop)">Generate Rate</button>
```

Javascript

// Setup

```
var CountrySet = [
    {
        "CountryName" : "Egypt",
        "ExchangeRate" : "25",
        "PrimRate" : "8.5",
        "SecRate" : "3.9",
        "TertRate" : "10.1"
    },
    {
        "CountryName" : "Finland",
        "ExchangeRate" : "45",
        "PrimRate" : "3",
        "SecRate" : "10.7",
        "TertRate" : "7.5"
    },
    {
        "CountryName" : "China",
        "ExchangeRate" : "35",
        "PrimRate" : "3.4",
        "SecRate" : "9.2",
        "TertRate" : "9.6"
    },
    {
        "CountryName" : "Germany",
        "ExchangeRate" : "30",
        "PrimRate" : "4.3",
        "SecRate" : "8.3",
        "TertRate" : "11.6"
    },
    {
        "CountryName" : "Afghanistan",
        "ExchangeRate" : "40",
        "PrimRate" : "5.6",
        "SecRate" : "5.3",
        "TertRate" : "10.5"
    },
    {
        "CountryName" : "UK",
        "ExchangeRate" : "55",
        "PrimRate" : "6.7",
        "SecRate" : "4.7",
        "TertRate" : "8.2"
    },
    {
        "CountryName" : "Russia",
        "ExchangeRate" : "50",
        "PrimRate" : "9.8",
        "SecRate" : "3.1",
        "TertRate" : "6.2"
    },
];
CountryName = document.getElementByName('A').value
prop = document.getElementByName('B').value

function LookUp(CountryName, prop) {
    for(var i = 0; i < CountrySet.length; i++){
        if (CountrySet[i].CountryName === CountryName) {
            if(CountrySet[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
                var ans = CountrySet[i][prop];
                document.getElementById("Rate").innerHTML = ans;

            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("Rate").innerHTML ="No Such Property";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `document.getElementByName('A').value` should be `getElementsByName("A")[0].value` I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```js
var CountrySet = [{
    "CountryName": "Egypt",
    "ExchangeRate": "25",
    "PrimRate": "8.5",
    "SecRate": "3.9",
    "TertRate": "10.1"
  },
  {
    "CountryName": "Finland",
    "ExchangeRate": "45",
    "PrimRate": "3",
    "SecRate": "10.7",
    "TertRate": "7.5"
  },
  {
    "CountryName": "China",
    "ExchangeRate": "35",
    "PrimRate": "3.4",
    "SecRate": "9.2",
    "TertRate": "9.6"
  },
  {
    "CountryName": "Germany",
    "ExchangeRate": "30",
    "PrimRate": "4.3",
    "SecRate": "8.3",
    "TertRate": "11.6"
  },
  {
    "CountryName": "Afghanistan",
    "ExchangeRate": "40",
    "PrimRate": "5.6",
    "SecRate": "5.3",
    "TertRate": "10.5"
  },
  {
    "CountryName": "UK",
    "ExchangeRate": "55",
    "PrimRate": "6.7",
    "SecRate": "4.7",
    "TertRate": "8.2"
  },
  {
    "CountryName": "Russia",
    "ExchangeRate": "50",
    "PrimRate": "9.8",
    "SecRate": "3.1",
    "TertRate": "6.2"
  },
];


function LookUp() {
  CountryName = document.getElementById('A').value;
  prop = document.getElementById('B').value;
  for (var i = 0; i < CountrySet.length; i++) {
    if (CountrySet[i].CountryName === CountryName) {
      if (CountrySet[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        var ans = CountrySet[i][prop];
        document.getElementById("Rate").innerHTML = ans;

      } else {
        document.getElementById("Rate").innerHTML = "No Such Property";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  Country Name: <input type="text" id="A"> <br> Rate Check: &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; <input type="text" id="B"> <br> Rate : <label id="Rate"> </label> <br>
</form> <br>
<button onclick="LookUp()">Generate Rate</button>
```

I made a couple of changes to get this to work.

1st change was to change `document.getElementByName` to `getElementById` and as well add an ID to your textfields.

2nd was to remove the arguments of your function because the way you are using them is incorrect

3rd was to move the actual variables within your function so you can fetch them after a user has submitted the form

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add some notes from response of N.Ivanov. You've typed command **getElementsByName** wrong. 
Second, it's better to use **getElementById** 'cause you could have multiple forms with same name on same page. Third and the last problem is that you have called onclick event which calls js function with parameters that are inside of it, so js couldn't make a call with such parameters.

Also, i would recommend jQuery if you are new to script languages.

### e.g. getting value of input field in jQuery:

```
var value = $('#a').val();
```